# Increasing and decreasing value of the clicks of the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi how can I make a button that will increase and decrease a value? I the button to add 1 when clicked once and reduced the value by 1 when clicked again so it can't count to more than 1.

I have around 50 buttons and currently, it resets when I choose more than 2 buttons, but it has to add all the values of the buttons that were clicked once. Site around it looks similar to this:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function clickME() {
  clicks += 1;
  if (clicks == 2) {
    clicks = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

```html
<input type="Button" id="bt" />
```

Comment: I've tried iwth this but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/57js0ps7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering each button (or more generically each element) is part of the DOM (Document Object Model), each one is an object, so no one makes you unable to use them: you can set the field `clicks` for each button DOM object:

```
function clickME(event) {
    var btn = event.target;
    btn.clicks = ((btn.clicks || 0) + 1) % 2;
    window.clicks = (window.clicks || 0) + btn.clicks * 2 - 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerText = window.clicks;
}
```

Checking out your code, I also simplified your logic replacing the `if` to check zero with the `MOD` (`%`) operator. Furthermore I replaced `innerHTML` with `innerText` because the number we won't to be rendered as HTML code, but as plain text, although in this case, it doesn't make difference.

**Note:**
Don't forget to pass the event data object with the `onclick` attribute in HTML:

```
<input onclick="clickME(event)" ...>
```

Check out this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/57js0ps7/2/

Comment: It doesn't count them all unfortunetly.

Comment: Sorry @mariie, I misunderstood the question. Reading it again I clarified your point: see the update in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a counter per each button individually - use an array to keep track of how many times a button has been clicked. If you don't the clicks var in your code will be two when you select 2 buttons and reset.

Answer (score 0):

On your html:

lets say you have 50 of these

```
<button type="button" data-clicked="false">1</button>
<button type="button" data-clicked="false">2</button>
```

and on your javascript

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.dataset.clicked == 'false') {
      this.dataset.clicked = 'true';
      this.innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML) + 1;
    }
    else {
      this.dataset.clicked = 'false'
      this.innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML) - 1;
    }
  })
});
```

EDIT: Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7fthtfr/)

Comment: But I need to get value of these two buttons summed up into other object so I can display it somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. do you mean you want to get the total values of all the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this tagged as jQuery here is a solution using jQuery. The solution involves using the `data-` attribute to hold the click count for each button (input). Not sure why you use inputs instead of buttons, but I kept that the same

It also has a getTotal() function that goes through each element and tallies the click to see how many slots were selected and displays that number for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click", clickME);
});

function clickME() {
  var clicks = $(this).data("clicks");
  var newClicks = parseInt(clicks) + 1;
  if(newClicks > 1){
    newClicks = 0;
  }
  // set the new click count on the element
  $(this).data("clicks", newClicks);
  setTotal();
}


function setTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".btn").each(function(imdex, btn) {
    var currClicks = parseInt($(btn).data("clicks"));
    total += currClicks;
  });
  $("#clicks").text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="0" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="1" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="2" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="3" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="4" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="5" />
<input type="Button" class="btn" data-clicks=0 value="6" />

<div>
  <p>You've choose <a id="clicks">0</a> slot/s.</p>
</div>
```